# Pie chart legend - how to specify the number of items?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a pie chart with a lot of categories:

[image]

Google Sheets automatically limits the number of items in the legend - in this case hiding 103 legend items.

Is there a way to manually control how many items are displayed?